# Probability measures on $\mathbb{T}$ whose Fourier coefficients tend to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, limits, fourier-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on the complex unit circle $\mathbb{T}$. Are the following two assertions equivalent?

1. $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\hat{\mu}(n)|=1$.
2. There exists an increasing sequence ${n_k}$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\hat{\mu}(n_k)=1$.

Comment: You don't want absolute values in the second limit?

Comment: That's the point.

Comment: Using Lebesgue decomposition theorem, we just have to deal with discrete measures.